# Error de sintaxis en create function

Tags: sql, postgresql, funciones

Estoy aprendiendo a hacer `funciones` en `sql` y tengo este problema:

El codigo es este, escrito en `pgadmin 4`

```
create function ventas_cliente(dni_cliente1 varchar (9)) returns int as                           
    select count(*) from ventas
    where dni_cliente1=$1
    group by dni_cliente1
    RETURN  int cantidad_ventas;
LENGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

me refuta el resultado asi:

```
ERROR:  error de sintaxis en o cerca de «select»
LINE 2:  select count(*) from ventas
         ^
Estado SQL: 42601
Caracter: 83
```

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas lenguage `plpgsql` para tu función debes tener el código entre bloques `BEGIN...END`, debes asignar el resultado de la consulta a una variable para retornarla y encapsular el código de tu función entre `$$` por ejemplo tu código quedaría como algo asi:

```
create function ventas_cliente(dni_cliente1 varchar (9)) returns int as   
$$
declare
cantidad_ventas int;
begin
    select count(*) into cantidad_ventas from ventas
    where dni_cliente1=$1
    group by dni_cliente1;
    RETURN  int cantidad_ventas;
end;   
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
```

También puedes tener la alternativa de hacer la función en lenguaje `SQL`

```
create function ventas_cliente_sql(dni_cliente1 varchar (9)) returns bigint as   
$$

    select count(*)  from ventas 
    where dni_cliente1=$1
    group by dni_cliente1;
$$
LANGUAGE 'sql'
```

Si deseas profundizar un poco más, te dejo [literatura al respecto en español](https://www.lulu.com/shop/anthony-r-sotolongo-le%C3%B3n-and-yudisney-vazquez-ortiz/plpgsql-y-otros-lenguajes-procedurales-en-postgresql/ebook/product-24129397.html?page=1&pageSize=4)

Comment: Flaco, muchisimas gracias por la respuesta, la solucion fue cambiar el int por un bigint